# I need to run macro on previous cell after clicking away on another and make some other modification changes

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I'm trying to create this excel macro sheet so that when I click on any cell(within table area) and enter some value, then if it sums equal to the key values(as given in attached image) of that row and column, it changes the cell color or else retains it.

[image]

```
Sub Add_Nos()

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim active As Integer

r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A").Value
c = Wor

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value

active = ActiveCell.Value
If active = r + c Then        
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    Call Add_Nos
End If

End Sub
```

I expect that when I enter some value in a cell and then click away on some other cell, it verifies the entered value and make color accordingly. But, after entering some value, when I click away and then click back again, then only it verifies and shows some color....

=>Also, I want to lock the values of key cells and change their color to keep them visually differentiated.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Be as precise as possible.

Comment: Tangential point: use `Long` rather than `Integer` in modern VBA. The number of rows in a spreadsheet can overflow that which can be stored in an integer variable (which is 16 bits).  Also with 32 or 64 bit operating systems, there is not performance advantage to using the smaller variable type, so you are just risking overflow for no good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code below is what you are trying to achieve:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Add_Nos(myRow As Long, myCol As Long, ByRef myTarget As Range)

Dim r As Long, c As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    r = .Cells(myRow, "A").Value
    c = .Cells(1, myCol).Value
End With

If myTarget.Value = r + c Then
    myTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    myTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If

End Sub

'===============================================================

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Add_Nos Target.Row, Target.Column, Target
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Please also help me resolve the other query from the post too... To lock the values of key cells(earlier recorded) and a color to make them visually differentiated.

Comment: @Shivam First, close this post, and if the solution I gave you worked, please mark as "answer". Now, you can open a new post on **SO*** with the lock issue, this will allow other users to assist.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the [imgur comments](https://imgur.com/gallery/chJUmho/comment/1564213589), go for conditional formatting! [image: See exemple]

This equation make the cell in red if the value of the cell is not equal to the sum of the row and column. You could replace the `<>` by `=` and change the format to a green color and now, you have the complete opposite (cells with good values are highlighted in green). Don't forget the `$` (or the lack of) in your range, as this is what make this efficient.